# Null object reference error in java with char arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, character

I have a `char[]` that I am attempting to append values to. However, at the line `newStringAr[count] = ar[j][i]`, I am receiving an error:  `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char java.lang.Character.charValue()' on a null object reference`.

When I changed my array to a `Character[]`, this error was resolved, but then I was not able to convert my array to a string as shown in the last line of the code sample below. How can I resolve this issue?

Note that `ar` is a previously-defined array of Characters (`Character[]` not `char[]`).

```
    int count = 0;
    char[] newStringAr = new char[ch.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ar.length; j++) {
            if (count<ch.length) {
                newStringAr[count] = ar[j][i];
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    String out = new String(newStringAr);
```

Comment: where did you declare the array `ar`?

Comment: I solved this issue by declaring `ar` as a char array, rather than a Character array. Reading the duplicate question really helped me, so thanks!